# RegEx - how to treat groups?

Tags: regex

I'm given a RegEx - `/((\D\d)+)(.{3})((\D(\d|\D)){2})/`

and a String to match it:

> R2D2BB8C3PO

What is caught by group **4**?

Now, am I supposed the answer it as if all the other groups didn't exist,
In this case I will catch `R2D2`

or I need to write what group **4** catched after all the other groups are done with their own catching?
In this case I will catch `C3PO`.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: [Check here](https://regex101.com/r/uN0dS2/1)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you need? `R2D2` is in Group 1, `C3PO` is in Group 4. You already match what you need with your regex.

Comment: My problem is clarification about groups, when i'm asked about a group do i need to treat it like it is the only thing that exists, or it is part of the whole RegEx?

Answer (score 0):

I presume the correct answer to the question is "C3PO", although it *is* a bit ambiguous, especially if you're sitting a test and have a tendency to over-think things like these. But the wording is "what is caught by group four" and not "what does group four match", which would be even more confusing.

Comment: Agreed.. I understand the answer is in terms of the definition.. I was hoping there would be like a general understanding but i guess only my professor could provide that..